# Calling Node.js functions from a C++ addon running in a separate Thread

Tags: c++, node.js

I have built a C++ addon for Node.js using Node's N-API. What I am trying is to call a JavaScript function from this addon, which works fine if the C++ code calling the JS-function is executed in the main thread of the addon. If I try to execute it (as a lambda function) from another thread (using std::thread), the function call throws a segmentation fault.

The lambda function is supposed to be called from another function running in another thread, as some kind of DataChanged notification.

This is the lambda function calling JS:

```
auto callbackFunction = [this]()->void {

    napi_value clb;

    napi_status status = napi_get_reference_value(this->env, this->callback, &clb);

    napi_value global;
    status = napi_get_global(this->env, &global);

    status = napi_create_int32(this->env, 47, &arg);

    napi_value arg;
    napi_value* argv = &arg;
    size_t argc = 1;

    napi_value retVal;
    status = napi_call_function(this->env, global, clb, argc, argv, &retVal);

    int32_t actRes;
    status = napi_get_value_int32(this->env, retVal, &actRes);
    cout << "Result: " << actRes << endl;
}
```

This works:

```
callbackFunction();
```

This throws a segmentation fault (on napi_call_function):

```
thread t(callbackFunction);
t.join();
```

Is there any chance to get this to work or do I need another solution for this?